# Why is the exponential map clearly the identity map for $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Suppose that $M$ is a smooth Riemannian manifold, $q\in M$. There exists an $\epsilon$ such that $\exp_q:B_{\epsilon}(0)\rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism.
In DoCarmo’s Riemannian Geometry book, it has been written that for $M=\mathbb R^n$, this map $\exp_q$ is the identity map, while $\exp_q(v)=q+v$. So what does DoCarmo mean?

Comment: What's your definition of the tangent space $T_q\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I identify it with $\mathbb R^n$ itself. Why?

Comment: Some people think in $T_q\mathbb{R}^n$ as the affine space $q + \mathbb{R}^n$ with the linear structure $(q+v)+(q+w)=q+(v+w)$ and $\lambda (q+v)=q+\lambda v$ for every $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks, I got what he meant now @DanteGrevino